# nicht müde, nur erschöpft

Tags: word-usage, difference

Ich habe neulich in einem Buch (von einer österreichischen Autorin) gelesen:

> Sie sollte schlafen gehen, aber sie fühlte sich nicht müde. Nur
> erschöpft.

Kann es so stark Unterschied sein für diese beiden Wörter?

Comment: Ich verstehe die Frage nicht. [Müde](https://www.dwds.de/wb/m%C3%BCde) und [erschöpft](https://www.dwds.de/wb/ersch%C3%B6pft) haben völlig verschiedene Bedeutungen.

Comment: @Olafant aha, [erschöpft](https://www.dwds.de/wb/ersch%C3%B6pft) (dein Link) : 1. am Ende der Kraft, vollkommen und anhaltend er**müdet**

Comment: Auch ermüdet hat mehr Bedeutungen als schlafbefürftig. Dass es teilweise Überschneidungen gibt, heißt nicht, dass die Bedeutungen nicht auch weit auseinanderliegen können.

Comment: Die Autorin hätte besser geschrieben: "sie fühlte sich nicht schläfrig, nur erschöpft". "müde" (= tired)  kann bedeuten, dass man schlafen möchte (schläfrig / sleepy), oder dass man keine Kraft mehr hat (erschöpft / exhausted).

Answer (score 1):

Es gibt Zustände, da ist man am Ende der Kräfte (erschöpft), kann aber nicht schlafen (hingegen könnte gemeint sein: wenn man müde ist, kann und will man schlafen). Also dass man statt zu schlafen ruhig sitzen und was Heißes trinken müsste...

Die Unterscheidung würde dann darauf beruhen, dass es für "müde" mehrere Lesarten gibt, und "müde = erschöpft" ist nur eine davon. Das wäre zB auch: "müde Füße / müde Beine", die können nicht schlafen :) müssen aber ausruhen. Im Zitat wird dann eine andere Lesart von "müde" erzwungen, indem man es in einen Gegensatz zu "erschöpft" stellt.